# Relative Template Import

Tags: python, django

I have a template located in `templates/mytemplate.html` in my app and I need to reference the template file directly in code to turn it into a string to use with `send_mail()`. How can I do this? Here's what I've tried:

```
from django.template import loader

html_message = loader.render_to_string(
            'appname/templates/mytemplate.html',
            {
                'username': user.name,
            }
        )
```

Comment: Have you tried just `mytemplate.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's the way your templates are set up, you should just be able to reference it by name

```
loader.render_to_string('mytemplate.html', {
    'username': user.name,
})
```

However be aware that in case you have any name conflicts within your Django project (or even if you don't), it's better to have a directory that mirrors the app name within your templates directory. Your tree structure for an app would look like this:

```
appname/
    some_file.py
    templates/
        appname/
            mytemplate.html
```

Then you would just reference it as `loader.render_to_string('appname/mytemplate.html', {...})`